# Register Broadcast Receiver from another Broadcast Receiver in android

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

Currently I have Broadcast Receiver for listening call states events. I have registered Broadcast Receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml` as shown below.

```
<receiver android:name=".api.PhoneCallReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When Application launches this broadcast receiver is registered for listening call states events and according to `CALL_STATE` i am managing my application.

It is working fine until phone restarts.
After phone restart this broadcast receiver stops working. I know I have to register receiver for listening `BOOT_COMPLETED` event of system.

What i have done is like shown below:

```
<receiver android:name=".api.PhoneCallReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
     </intent-filter>
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have also given Permission for getting `BOOT_COMPLETED` system event.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

but somehow it is not working. I am thinking of making new Broadcast Receiver that listens for `BOOT_COMPLETED` event only but issue is that

So my questions is how can i start this Phone Call Listener Broadcast Receiver when any incoming call comes in?

How can i register Broadcast Receiver from another Broadcast Receiver

Do i have to move my existing broadcast receiver's code to service so i can start service from Boot Receiver?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have given the permission, ok, but did you request this permission at runtime if you develop target =>API23 ?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs current targetSdkVersion is 22 for app.

Comment: ok, and do you have the permission READ_PHONE_STATE?

Comment: Yes. READ_PHONE_STATE is allowed and Broadcast receiver works as expected until phone restarts

Comment: That´s a very good question, I never used that case, so I don´t know. Have you tried to register the receiver simply inside onBoot completed?

Comment: No I have not tried this case. will get back to you after checking

Comment: I can´t find any documentation about registering a receiver programmatically that is also registered via manifest. But usually, on a in manifest registered receiver, a registered receiver receives the intent automatically, so your READ_PHONE_STATE should work even without inBootCompleted...

Comment: One more question: Your target is API22, but which is installed on your device? If you have MM, then it´s possible that this permissions are not given automatically and you have to do it manually.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Thanks for guiding. I have solved it by registering dynamic broadcast receiver.

Comment: You can't register a Receiver directly on the `Context` passed into another `Receiver`'s `onReceive()` method. And you don't need to. You've registered it in the manifest. You don't need to register it dynamically. It's already "started", just by being registered in the manifest. That's why it works before rebooting.

Comment: @MikeM. then why it is not working after rebooting?

Comment: Oh, I missed that part. I just saw the registering a Receiver in a Receiver part. It absolutely should work. Are you forcibly closing your app before you reboot?

Comment: @MikeM. no i am not forcibly closing your app before you reboot

Comment: How are you determining that the Receiver isn't working? Are you testing on a device or an emulator? Which Android version are you running under?

Comment: I am testing on real device Lenovo K3 note. Os version is 6.0. I am starting one activity that shows contact information from my app database when any incoming call comes in. It works until phone reboots.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what to tell you, other than to suggest trying it on a different system. If you see the same behavior, then your code must not be setup like I'm assuming it is. Are you handling Marshmallow's runtime permissions, if necessary? Are you dynamically registering a Receiver anywhere else in the app that might be what's actually running at first? Have you tried logging in the Receiver, to see if it runs at all, and maybe the `Activity` is just failing? I'm not aware of any changes in 6 that would necessarily cause the described behavior, but I'll test on that when I get a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any Other answers are welcome.

I have solved it by creating new Broadcast receiver and `onReceive()` method of that Broadcast receiver will be called when phone restarts then i have dynamically register `READ_PHONE_STATE` broadcast receiver that is also manifest registered receiver.

Below is code:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<receiver android:name=".api.ServiceStarter">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
public class ServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
        PhoneCallReceiver receiver = new PhoneCallReceiver();
        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}
```

You have to register receiver using Application context like below:

```
context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

instead of

```
context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Otherwise you will get following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   com.ecosmob.contactpro.api.ServiceStarter:
>   android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver
>   components are not allowed to register to receive intents

I hope it helps others!