# Android Oreo Receiver Stops If Removed App From Recents

Tags: java, android, manifest, receiver

Receiver works on all android versions from 4.2 upto 8.0. Even if app is removed from `Recent Apps` But if removed from `Recent Apps` in Android Oreo, it then never triggers receiver again.

my manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".WatchMan"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>


</application>
```

---

My receiver.java :

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
public String PhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    Log.d("RECEIVER :","CAPTURED THE EVENT.....");

    try
    {
        PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
             context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
        }
        else
        {
             context.startService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("RECEIVER EXCEPTION : ", "Exception is : ", e);
    }

}
```

I want to know if i am doing any mistake in code? `Android Developers Documentation` asking to register receiver runtime using `context`. Then i searched for registering it in runtime on `stackoverflow` but looks no proper thread accepted as answer. How can make receiver to to be ready again, even if removed from `recents` of `Android Oreo`?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787291/register-broadcast-receiver-from-another-broadcast-receiver-in-android  found one trying  it... May be it will work...??!!

Comment: No it did not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted unrelated posts. I am posting final answer as it may help others. @WIZARD help was thankful.

---

```
PHONE_STATE is implicit and will not be triggered on android Oreo or higher. So just place permissions in manifest like :
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".WatchMan"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".CatchNumbers"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>
```

---

Register implicit receivers from foreground service :

```
public class WatchMan extends Service
{
NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "17";
private boolean running;

private BroadcastReceiver mCallBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String PhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";
        Log.d("RECEIVER :  ","HERE HERE");

        try
        {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if(state == null)
            {
                PhoneNumber = "UNKNOWN";
            }
            else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.d("INCOMING ","Incoming number : "+PhoneNumber);
            }
            if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
            {

                PhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                Log.d("OUTGOING ","Outgoing number : "+PhoneNumber);

            }


            if(!PhoneNumber.contentEquals("UNKNOWN"))
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                {
                    context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class));
                }
                else
                {
                    context.startService(new Intent(context, CatchNumbers.class));
                }
            }



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("RECEIVER EXCEPTION : ", "Exception is : ", e);
        }
    }
};

public WatchMan() { }

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);

    IntentFilter filterstate = new IntentFilter();
    filterstate.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    filterstate.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    this.registerReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver, filterstate);

    Log.d("RECEIVER : ", "\nCreated....");

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Insta Promo")
            .setContentText("Insta Promo Is Up..")
            .setTicker("Insta Promo Is Up..")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {

        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

    running = true;

    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    startForeground(17, mBuilder.build());



}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d("RECEIVER : ", "\nOnStartCommand....");
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(running)
            {
                try
                {
                    Log.d("RECEIVER : ", "\nALIVE..");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Log.d("RECEIVER : ", "\nThread : InterruptedException in Receiver...");
                    Log.e("RECEIVER : ", "\nException is : ", e);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.d("RECEIVER : ", "\nThread : Exception Error in Receiver...");
                    Log.e("RECEIVER : ", "\nException is : ", e);
                }
            }

        }

    }).start();



    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    this.unregisterReceiver(mCallBroadcastReceiver);
    running = true;
    Log.d("RECEIVER : ", "\nDestroyed....");
    Log.d("RECEIVER : ", "\nWill be created again....");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.d("SERVICE : ", "\nTask Removed....");
}


}
```

---

There are some intent actions like NEW_OUTGOING_CALL AND BOOT_COMPLETED  which are excluded and can be implemented in receiver and placed in manifest like :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.d("INSTA_BOOT : ", "\nBOOT_COMPLETE_EVENT_OF_INSTA....");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
    }
    else
    {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, WatchMan.class));
    }
}
}
```

As i wanted to re-register or say want to restart foreground service on REBOOT OR BOOT-COMPLETE

---

```
CatchNumbers.java is a simple service which performs operation when receiver triggers perticular actions.
```

---

It works good on every restart and as `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` is not needed anymore as even if user removes it from `recents` on Oreo it will restart the service as it is `STICKY`. Hope it helps someone like me..!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts) for restrictions on implicit broadcast in Android 8, you **cannot** use implicit receivers in your manifest (although there are some exceptions, but phone state receiver is not among those exceptions)

You have to use foreground service and register your receiver in your foreground service instead of manifest

**remove phone state receiver from manifest**

register receiver in onCreate of Service:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        phoneStateReceiver = new PhoneStateReceiver();
        registerReceiver(phoneStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED));
    }
```

unregister in onDestroy:

```
   @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(phoneStateReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

add a static method to your service to start service:

```
// start service even if your app is in stopped condition in android 8+
static void requestStart(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final String action){
        final Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, AppService.class);
        intent.setAction(action);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // this is required to start the service if there is 
            // no foreground process in your app and your app is
            // stopped in android 8 or above
            appContext.startForegroundService(intent);
        } else {
            appContext.startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

start foreground in your `onStartCommand`

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         if(ACTION_START.equals(intent.getAction()))
           startForeground(ID, notification);
         else if(ACTION_STOP.equals(intent.getAction()))
           stopForeground(true);

         return START_STICKY;
}
```